# Android studio error when setting visibility

Tags: android, kotlin

This error keeps appearing even though I am pretty sure I referenced the correct `View`/`toolbar`.

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference`

My goals is to build a fragment which has a different `toolbar` then the `MainActivity`, I did not set any of the `toolbars` as an `Actionbar` as there is no need for it.

**MainActivity XML**

```
<include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/customToolbarInclude"
    ></include>

<include layout="@layout/second_toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/secondLayoutInclude"
   ></include>
```

**Activity Toolbar XML**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarcover"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/MenuToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/MyToolbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:titleCentered="true"
        android:elevation="30dp">
       ...
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
```

**The unique toolbar**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBarthesecond"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:visibility="gone"
        style="@style/MyToolbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:titleCentered="true"
        android:elevation="30dp">
        
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
```

**The Fragment I tried to switch the toolbar**

```
val mainToolbar = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.MenuToolBar)
val SecondaryToolBar = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.topAppBarthesecond)

    mainToolbar.visibility = View.GONE
    SecondaryToolBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Specifically the error mentioned above occurs at the line `mainToolbar.visibility = View.GONE`, which I do not understand, I am referencing the `toolbar` how is it `null`? It works perfectly fine when I do it in `XML`

Comment: The error tells you that one of the toolbar variables is null, so one of your `findViewById` calls returns null. This can happen if the layout isn't inflated yet, or if the view you are finding is not in the current layout, or if the view is the wrong type. This is the sort of error you need to either debug yourself or provide enough code so someone else could replicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should always check is which one is `null`, the `view` or the `mainToolbar`?

- If the `mainToolbar` is `null` while the `view` isn't, you probably do something wrong when inflating the view.
- If the `view` is `null`, the most probable cause is that the code snippet you posted is being executed before the view has successfully been inflated; for example, it's written in the `onCreate(..)` and not in the `onViewCreated(..)`.

Be sure you respect the view's lifecycle when doing any view operation.

[image]